Sorce IP with Azure Front Door and Ingress-nginx
I have a keycloak instance running on kubernetes. Users are accessing keycloak via AzureFrontDoor->Ingress-Nginx->Kubernetes
I am trying to get keycloak to display the source IP of client however the client IP displayed in keycloak is the IP address of Azure Front Door.
Since keycloak is showing the IP address of the frontdoor, I am assuming that keycloak is configured correctly and the issue lies somewhere between frontdoor and ingress-nginx configuration.
Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?
ingress:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-forwarded-headers: "true"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-add-original-forwarded-for: "true"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarded-for-header: "michele"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/real-ip-header: "X-Forwarded-For"


Nginx-Ingress Settings configuration


  settings = [
    {
      name  = "controller.ingressClassResource.name"
      value = "nginx-external-frontdoor"
      type  = "string"
    },
    {
      name  = "controller.ingressClassResource.controllerValue"
      value = "k8s.io/ingress-nginx-external-frontdoor"
      type  = "string"
    },

    {
      name  = "controller.service.type"
      value = "LoadBalancer"
      type  = "string"
    },
    {
      name  = "controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy"
      value = "Local"
      type  = "string"
    }
  ]
}



At the end I was missing the following annotation on nginx-ingress config-map. It immediately started working.
    {
      name  = "controller.config.use-forwarded-headers"
      value = "true"
      type  = "string"
    }

